# Extract youtube link from db - fancybox bug or what?

Tags: mysql, iframe, fancybox

Hello, I have problems with fancybox 2. I extract a youtube link from a mySQL database, but this don't work. However, if I write the youtube link in the src tag, then everything is ok.

```
<p></p><a class='youtube info'  href='".$myrow[ylink]."'>Смотреть трейлер</a> // doesn't work


<p></p><a class='youtube info'  href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1v0uFms68U'>Смотреть трейлер</a>  // works
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is not complete, but I guess you missed to enter into php-mode.

```
<p></p><a class='youtube info'  href='<?php echo $myrow['ylink'];?>'>Смотреть трейлер</a>
```